# Bootstrap can not override attribute of <p>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap, which has the following element:

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

I do not want to have empty space at the end of the tag so I wrote the following:

```
.p {
    margin: 0 0 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

However, the empty space still appears at the bottom.

When I look at the Chrome Developer Tools, the `p` element is unchanged.

Why is my CSS code not changing the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.p` means that you are referring to class `p`.

If you want to modify some properties of `p` tag, simply use `p`

So that,

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.p` selects an element with a class of `p` eg. `<span class="p"></span>`

You want the following...

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```